# Installing 3rd party plug in on Edge through Registry Editor / GPO

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, microsoft-edge

I am trying to install 3rd party plug in to Microsoft Edge without the need for user involvement.

Is there any way that I can do it through registry editor or GPO and push it down to all clients.

This is the plug in that I am trying to install https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ie-tab/npjkkakdacjaihjaoeliacmecofghagh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could install an extension without user involvement.

You need to configure the group policy [Control which extensions are installed silently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#control-which-extensions-are-installed-silently)

- GP unique name: ExtensionInstallForcelist
- GP name: Control which extensions are installed silently
- GP path (Mandatory): Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/Extensions
- GP path (Recommended): N/A
- GP ADMX file name: MSEdge.admx

You need to pass the extension id/ app id as a parameter to this group policy.

You have shared the extension link in the original post. You could notice the last part after `/` is the app id.

Helpful Reference: [Force-install an extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-manage-extensions-policies#force-install-an-extension)

Note: The features provided by that extension comes by default in the Edge browser. It is known as [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#what-is-ie-mode).

Comment: How can i find out the Extension id / app id ??

Comment: If you see the extension link you have shared in the question, after the last `/` the string is the app id. In your case, it is `npjkkakdacjaihjaoeliacmecofghagh`.